# C# code issue - Code not working properly

Tags: c#, debugging

I wrote a basic number guessing game from C#. It seems to return the 3rd option ("Wrong choice! Please try again.") every time no matter what var c is chosen by the user. I was trying with characters (s instead of 1 and w instead of 2 etc with c as a string) but it gave the same results. Not sure where it's going bad.

```
using System;

namespace Challanges
{
    class Program
    {
        static int guess = 500;
        static int low = 1;
        static int high = 1000;
        static bool cont = false;


        static void Guess() //guesses and adjusts variables according to input.
        {
            int c;
            Console.WriteLine("Is your number greater or less than: " + guess + Environment.NewLine + "If it is less than, press 1; if it is greater, press 2." + Environment.NewLine + "If it is your number, press 3.");
            c = Convert.ToInt32(Console.Read());

            if (c == 1)
            {
                high = 500;
                guess = low + high / 2;
            }
            else if (c == 2)
            {
                low = 500;
                guess = low + high / 2;
            }
            else if (c == 3)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Congratulations!! We found your number!");
                cont = true;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Wrong choice! Please try again.");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {


            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!" + Environment.NewLine + "Let's play a guessing game. Think of a number between 1 and 1000." + Environment.NewLine + "Type your number :)");
            int x = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Your number is: " + x + Environment.NewLine + "Too easy?");
            Console.ReadKey();
            Console.WriteLine("Think of a number");
            if(cont == false)
            {
                Guess();

            } else
            {
                Console.ReadKey();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does the debugger say about the value of c?

Comment: Have you tried to debug it? Check out some basic YouTube or etc video's on debugging

Comment: `Console.Read` returns character codes. The character code for `1` is not 1. See also the [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.console.read#examples).

Comment: Probably you should read the docs to learn the differences between Read(), ReadLine() and ReadKey(), it seems in your code you use them interchangeably and possibly randomly, without an obvious pattern or logic. However, they are different and do different things (otherwise there would only be one such method!), and this is having an impact on your code.

Comment: I was going to have a bitch about *is this the community we want to be* but then I read your profile **By Night: A procastinating couch patato working to complete homework.** - so it's a homework question. Dude, you actually need to learn yourself...

Comment: @JeremyThompson What does this have to do with the question, there is no difference if we are helping people do there job or homework, at least he has written some code, so there is effort involved

Comment: @JeremyThompson I am also with Icepickle on this. He tried himself but was facing errors he could not handle alone, so he came for help. Seems perfectly legid to me.

Comment: Fine, I just don't agree procrastinating and occasionally get tired of ppl using us as their homework debuggers. Give a man a fish, or teach him how to fish...  I get your point, that's why I was going to disagree with all the downvotes.. and let's not overlook I encouraged him to skill up in debugging.

Comment: @JeremyThompson Not homework. Learning cause why not. I'm a biochem major, don't really ever use coding. Believe it or not, I'm at work, overnight, nothing to do, spent the last 3 hours trying to fix it (I'm a beginner so it takes a while). Though I am a procrastinating couch potato :/ I'm gonna reply to rest once I learn a bit more on debugging.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the comments before, `Console.Read()` returns a character code. The character code for the number 1 is 49, thus your conditions fail and the else block is executed.

What you wanted to do was use `Console.ReadLine()`which returns a string instead of character codes. If you cast that `string` into an `Int32` you should be able to evaluate your conditions correctly.

Comment: I tried that first and it didn't work but it did now. It worked with numbers but now guess var just goes to the extremes after 2nd user input. I'll try to fix it myself. Will comment again if I can't figure it out. Also gonna try to use letters instead for input.

Comment: It works. Thanks. Gonna read up to see why ReadKey doesn't work.